# Python path and virtualenv problems on windows

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pythonpath

My python is installed in c:\python27 and my site-packages is located in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. The problem, that I couldn't understand, is why if I put a script called base-install.py in site-packages and call it using

```
C:\Users\max>python base-install.py
python: can't open file 'base-install.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The second problem is that I have same issue with virtualenv. When I create it and activate it with Scripts\activate.bat, if I try to call, for example python django-admin.py(which is correctly installed in site-packages of virtenv) I have same issue:

```
(test2) D:\www\test2>python django-admin.py
python: can't open file 'django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am stuck with this since 2 hours and I can't get where I mess it up.

Comment: Seems like your path is not set correctly.

Comment: i didn't touch it, what can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the *python module search path* with the *file system path*.

When you type this:

`C:\Users\max>python base-install.py`

`python` = This works, because the python executable (python.exe) is in your file system path. The Python installer adds the location of `python.exe` to your global file system path.

`base-install.py` This file is not in any directory that is in your file system path, and it is not in the directory `max` from where you are running the command, which is why you are getting the error.

The second problem is a bit easier to solve. In Windows, scripts are added to a `Scripts` directory:

Simply do:

`(test2) D:\www\test2>python Scripts\django-admin.py`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute that script from some other location you shoud do:

```
    python -m base-install
```

This way if base-install.py is either in site-packages or in any other directory added to `PYTHONPATH` it should work.